# Updated to Xcode 8: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode

My Project was compiling just fine with Xcode 7. After I updated to Xcode 8 I am getting error on archiving as

```
ARM_RELOC_SECTDIFF missing following pair file '/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cpqbgodogioovqeqfklrrjxasaeq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Project.build/Release-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ClassName.o' for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove the **armv7 architecture** it starts to work fine. But then I loose support for iPhone 5. it says missing  pair file for my class. Any help what this issue could be?